# Why does my scan tool still report a security issue?

Tags: java, security, iso, fortify

Our application uses HP Fortify to scan for security vulnerabilities.  One vulnerability that it’s found is the Unreleased Resource: Database vulnerability.

The abstract suggests this as a solution:

```
public void execCxnSql(Connection conn) {

Statement stmt;

try {

stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(CXN_SQL);

...

}

finally {

if (stmt != null) {

safeClose(stmt);

}

}

}

public static void safeClose(Statement stmt) {

if (stmt != null) {

try {

stmt.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {

log(e);

}

}

}
```

Which I have implemented to some success on the following type of database connection closure:

```
if(conn != null){

try{

    conn.rollback();

    conn.Close(); // Report indicates an issue here

}catch SQLException{}
```

By transforming it into this:

```
if(conn != null){

try{

    conn.rollback();

}catch SQLException{}

finally{

safeClose(conn);  //Issue no longer reported

}



public static void safeClose(Connection stmt) {

if (stmt != null) {

try {

stmt.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {

log(e);

}

}

}
```

(Note: “Connection” is an SQL database connection)

However, attempting the same fix on this type of database closure:

```
if(conn != null){

try{

    conn.commit ();

    conn.Close(); // report indicates an issue here

}catch SQLException{}
```

Does not remove the issue from our security scan.

```
if(conn != null){

try{

    conn.commit();

}catch SQLException{}

finally{

safeClose(conn); // Issue not resolved

}
```

**(Note our app is Java 1.4, so we cannot use "try-with-resourses")**

The actual scan doesn’t go into detail as to why the two are different – so assuming all other things about the application’s use of the connection are the same (and they are as far as I can tell), what reason would it have for reporting a security issue in one case, and not the other?

Comment: The code is syntactically incorrect. Java is case sensitive, so `If`, `Try` and `Finally` are all wrong. In addition to that the code is horrible in other ways too. Using `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement` for example, empty catch blocks... You could use `try-with-resources` to make it both correct **and** a lot nicer looking, but I assume you're using some outdated version of Java.

Comment: The bad casing is a case of "I put this in word doc before posting and couldn't be bothered to remove the casing", but I will edit it. And the "statement" is from the scan example. I've also put proper logging in my functioning code, but left it all out because it had security sensitive data.  And yes, we're stuck in 1.4, so sadly we can't use try-with-resourses yet.

Comment: Ah, the horrors of legacy code..

Answer (score 1):

```
if(conn != null){

try{

    conn.commit ();

    conn.Close(); // report indicates an issue here

}catch SQLException{}
```

So `conn.close()` will not be executed if `conn.commit()` throws `SQLException`, or for that matter any other exception.

As you guessed, move it to `finally` should resolve the issue if it resolves it in the other case.

Further, since `Connection` is `AutoCloseable` consider using `try-with-resources`

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried exactly as you said (encapsulated in a separate method) and it still reports the issue. Also, I'm on 1.4 so I can't use try-with-resourses, but I will add that since I only mentioned it in comments